# Enumeration through hash and keeping separate key value pairs of a key that are the same

Tags: ruby

I have this array of objects:

```
a = [#<Person id: 9, name: "Bob", bin_id: "114628">, 
   #<Person id: 10, name: "Sally", bin_id: "114626">, 
   #<Person id: 11, name: "Jessie", bin_id: "114627">, 
   #<Person id: 12, name: "Rapheal", bin_id: "114620">, 
   #<Company _id: 55295, name: "X", bin_id: "114619">, 
   #<Company _id: 55295, name: "Y", bin_id: "114629">, 
   #<Company _id: 55295, name: "Z", bin_id: "16074802">, 
   #<Company _id: 55295, name: "W", bin_id: "16074815">]
```

When I do

```
a.group_by { |objects| object.calculate_age }
```

I get this:

```
 { 
     33 => 
            [#<Person id: 9, name: "Bob", bin_id: "114628">, 
            #<Person id: 10, name: "Sally", bin_id: "114626">, 
            #<Person id: 11, name: "Jessie", bin_id: "114627">],
     53 => [#<Company _id: 55295, name: "X", bin_id: "114619">],
     45 => [#<Company _id: 55295, name: "Y", bin_id: "114629">,],
     56 => [#<Company _id: 55295, name: "Z", bin_id: "16074802">],
     60 => [#<Company _id: 55295, name: "W", bin_id: "16074815">]
 }
```

But how I do get something that looks like this:

```
 {   
     33 => [#<Person id: 9, name: "Bob", bin_id: "114628">], 
     33 => [#<Person id: 10, name: "Sally", bin_id: "114626">], 
     33 => [#<Person id: 11, name: "Jessie", bin_id: "114627">],
     53 => [#<Company _id: 55295, name: "X", bin_id: "114619">],
     45 => [#<Company _id: 55295, name: "Y", bin_id: "114629">,],
     56 => [#<Company _id: 55295, name: "Z", bin_id: "16074802">],
     60 => [#<Company _id: 55295, name: "W", bin_id: "16074815">]
    }
```

Where each key is explicitely set to each value?  Maybe `group_by` isn't the right method here.  I want to return a hash like you see above.

Comment: keys must be unique in a hash - what you ask for doesn't make sense.

Comment: You can't. As @FrederickCheung said, keys must be unique. That means you can't have three `33` keys; The last one added will win. Typically we'd use an array for the value in the pair, which contains the multiple objects you're interested in, just as `group_by` is creating for you. The [Hash documentation](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.1/Hash.html) says "A Hash is a dictionary-like collection of unique keys and their values.".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the purposes of your question, you could write your array:

```
arr = [obj0, obj1,...,obj7]
```

since the values of the each object's instance variables are irrelevant. You can't convert that to a hash with duplicate keys (`age`), but you could convert it to an array of hashes, each with a single key, `age`, if that would be helpful:

```
arr.map { |obj| { obj.calculate_age=>obj } }
```

To see how that would work, suppose we have:

```
class Friends
  attr_reader :calculate_age
  def initialize name, age
    @name, @calculate_age = name, age
  end
end

a = [["Amy", 21], ["Billy-Bob", 53], ["Wilber", 21], ["Trixi", 34], ["Bo", 53]]
arr = a.map { |name,age| Friends.new(name,age) }
  #=> [#<Friends:0x007fc1f28b5518 @name="Amy", @calculate_age=21>,
  #    #<Friends:0x007fc1f28b54a0 @name="Billy-Bob", @calculate_age=53>,
  #    #<Friends:0x007fc1f28b5450 @name="Wilber", @calculate_age=21>,
  #    #<Friends:0x007fc1f28b5400 @name="Trixi", @calculate_age=34>,
  #    #<Friends:0x007fc1f28b5388 @name="Bo", @calculate_age=53>]
```

We can now convert this to an array of hashes:

```
a = arr.map { |obj| { obj.calculate_age=>obj } }
  #=> [{21=>#<Friends:0x007fc1f28b5518 @name="Amy",...},
  #    {53=>#<Friends:0x007fc1f28b54a0 @name="Billy-Bob",...},
  #    {21=>#<Friends:0x007fc1f28b5450 @name="Wilber"...},
  #    {34=>#<Friends:0x007fc1f28b5400 @name="Trixi"...},
  #    {53=>#<Friends:0x007fc1f28b5388 @name="Bo",...}]
```

If you want those arrays sorted by age:

```
a.sort_by { |h| h.keys.first }
  #=> [{21=>#<Friends:0x007fc1f28b5518 @name="Amy",...},
  #    {21=>#<Friends:0x007fc1f28b5450 @name="Wilber"...},
  #    {34=>#<Friends:0x007fc1f28b5400 @name="Trixi"...},
  #    {53=>#<Friends:0x007fc1f28b54a0 @name="Billy-Bob",...},
  #    {53=>#<Friends:0x007fc1f28b5388 @name="Bo",...}]
```

Comment: I like this solution as it gives you the closest possible thing to what you were asking – which unfortunately is not possible in ruby (as others have said, `Hash` keys must be unique). Yet, I think that the output of good old `group_by` is just easier to work with.

Comment: Thanks everyone and Cary.  This solution was helpful.  I appreciate your help and everyone elses!

Comment: Hey, I'm an everyone too!